# Replace missings SAS

Tags: sql, sas

I have two tables:

```
data a;
input a b c;
datalines;
1 2 .
;
run;

data b;
input a b c;
datalines;
1 . 3
;
run;
```

The result I want from these tables is replacing the missings by the values that are not missing:

```
a b c
-----
1 2 3
```

How can I do it with mostly less piece of code?

EDIT:
I wrote the code and it works, but may be there is more simple code for this.

```
%macro x;
%macro dummy; %mend dummy;
    data _null_;
        set x end=Last;
        call symputx("name"||left(_N_),name);
        if Last then call symputx("num",_n_);
    run;

    data c;
        set a b;
    run;

    data c;
        set c;
        %do i=1 %to &num;
            x&i=lag(&&name&i);
        %end;
        n=_n_;
    run;

    data c1 (drop= n %do i=1 %to &num; x&i %end;);
        set c (where=(n=2));
        %do i=1 %to &num;
            if missing(&&name&i) and not missing(x&i) then &&name&i=x&i;
        %end;
    run;
%mend;
%x;
```

Comment: I don't understand why you wrote your code the way you did.  Why write a macro specifically so you can have multiple levels, but then hardcode `where n=2` which means this will only work for the 2nd level?  In general this is a reasonable approach, but it's an approach that suggests you know macro coding better than SAS data step.  Probably worth spending some time learning/practicing intermediate SAS data step techniques, as your macro understanding is probably better than your SAS data step understanding.

Comment: For example, your two `data c` are unneeded - combine those two into one dataset.  I'll write a separate answer explaining how to do this approach (even though I don't think I'd use it myself).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `proc SQL`, you can do this with aggregation:

```
proc sql;
    select max(a) as a, max(b) as b, max(c) as c
    from (select a, b, c from a union all
          select a, b, c from b
         ) x;
```

If, as I suspect, the first column is an id for matching the two tables, you should instead do:

```
proc sql;
    select coalesce(a.a, b.a), coalesce(a.b, b.b) as b, coalesce(a.c, b.c) as c
    from a full join
         b
         on a.a = b.a;
```

Answer (score 3):

If the values are consistent, ie, you never have:

```
1 2 3
1 3 .
```

and/or are happy for them to be overwritten, then UPDATE is excellent for this.

```
data c;
  update a b;
  by a;
run;
```

`UPDATE` will only replace values with non-missing values, so `.` gets replaced by `3` but `2` is not replaced by `.`.  Again assuming `a` is the ID variable as Gordon assumes.

You also can easily do this:

```
data c;
  set a b;
  by a;
  retain b_1 c_1;
  if first.a then do;  *save the first b and c;
    b_1=b;
    c_1=c;
  end;
  else do;             *now fill in missings using COALESCE which only replaces if missing;
    b_1=coalesce(b_1,b);  *use coalescec if this is a char var;
    c_1=coalesce(c_1,c);  *same;
  end;
  if last.a then output;  *output last row;
  drop b c;
  rename
    b_1=b
    c_1=c
  ;
run;
```

This makes sure you keep the *first* instance of any particular value, if they may be different (the opposite of `update` which keeps the *last* instance, and different from the SQL solution which takes MAX specifically).  All three should give the same result if you have only identical values.  Data step options should be a bit faster than the SQL option, I expect, as they're both one pass solutions with no matching required (though it probably doesn't matter).

Comment: Updated answer to have UPDATE instead of MODIFY - that's really the better term.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to post how to do your approach with some details here: I wouldn't consider this the best approach for this, but you can perhaps learn more easily by starting with what you have, and it's not a horrible approach certainly - just not optimal.

Starting:

```
%macro x;
%macro dummy; %mend dummy;
    data _null_;
        set x end=Last;
        call symputx("name"||left(_N_),name);
        if Last then call symputx("num",_n_);
    run;

    data c;
        set a b;
    run;

    data c;  *NOTE 1;
        set c;
        %do i=1 %to &num;
            x&i=lag(&&name&i);  *NOTE 2;
        %end;
        n=_n_;
    run;

    data c1 (drop= n %do i=1 %to &num; x&i %end;);   *NOTE 3;
        set c (where=(n=2));
        %do i=1 %to &num;
            if missing(&&name&i) and not missing(x&i) then &&name&i=x&i;
        %end;
    run;
%mend;
%x;
```

Ending:

```
*You can still do the first datastep to figure out the dimensions of the arrays, 
 if you want, use &num instead of the 3s hardcoded in there (but do not need &name list).;

data c;
  set a(in=in_a) b(in=in_b);
  array x[3] _temporary_;   *NOTE 4;
  array var[3] a b c;
  do i = 1 to dim(x);       *NOTE 5;
    x[i] = lag(vars[i]);
  end;
  if in_b then do;          *NOTE 6;
    do i=1 to dim(x);
      if missing(vars[i]) then vars[i]=x[i];  *NOTE 7;
    end;
    output;
  end;
run;
```

Notes:

NOTE 1:  You can combine the two `c` datasteps here with no difference at all.  In general have as few data steps as you can, as they're slow - this is a difference from R or similar which use in memory processing, in SAS you use disk processing which is nice for ability to do 200GB of data but not as fast for multiple steps like this - so make fewer steps.

NOTE 2: This is basically a macro implementation of an array.  SAS datastep has an array already!  Use it.

NOTE 3: You don't need to do the drop like that.  `drop=n x:` works fine as long as none of your real variables start with `x` (and if they do, use an _ before all of your dummy variables and it will be the same).  `:` is a wild card for 'starts with'.

NOTE 4: Here is the array implementation of your `x` array.  I use `temporary` because that means the variables will be dropped automatically for you.

NOTE 5: Here we do the lags.  I don't like using `lag` for this where `retain` does a better job of the same thing, but it works fine.

NOTE 6: This `if in_b` is like your `if last` from your step.  This identifies records in `b` only - if there's only one then it will only  happen once.

NOTE 7: This is doing the replacement for missing.  `COALESCE` \ `COALESCEC` would also work for this purpose (though in some cases you might need to use this method if you are unsure of the variable type).  No reason to check `if not missing` unless you're using special missings in some fashion - no harm in replacing `.` with `.`.

Comment: How to avoid using macro if names of columns are unknown? I used proc transpose with (out=x) option before macro definition to get the columns names.

Comment: If it's _all_ variables, then you can use a few shortcuts.  `_numeric_` is all numeric variables, for example, so you could say `array vars _numeric_;` and it would include all numeric variables.  Then define `x` to have an arbitrarily large number of members (so it's safely higher than vars) and use `dim(Vars)` everywhere (never use `dim(x)`) and you're fine.

Comment: In the case that you use `array vars _numeric_;` you have to also define the temporary array long enough.  However, you don't actually know how long to make it!  As such you just make it really big (big enough you're sure it will be more than `vars`).  However, then you want to iterate over `vars` - and `dim(x)` will be much higher than `dim(vars)`, so use the latter.

Comment: IE, in your case above (3 vars), you have `array vars _numeric_; array x[1000] _temporary_;` then `dim(Vars)=3` and `dim(x)=1000`, say.  You want to iterate from 1 to 3, not from 1 to 1000 - x is 1000 just to make sure it's more than 3.

Comment: Okay thanks. But how to do the same thing for case when there is unknown number of rows also? IE we sort set a b by ID and there are 100 rows. The output row must contain the data for the "latest" ID.

Comment: MODIFY is the best way to do it I think then.  That will give you the data from the latest ID that has data for each variable, if that's what you want.

Comment: Yes I tried your statement from above but It said:
ERROR 416-185: The MODIFY statement requires the MASTER data set to be present on the DATA statement.

Comment: You can similarly use UPDATE, that's probably right for this case.